# Going through customs in a foreign country. I want to delete my monerujo app. Can I re-download with everything intact?

Tags: android-wallet, monerujo

I've read that you can delete and restore the monerujo app without affecting the wallet data, I never tried it as I'm afraid of losing access to my wallets.

When you setup your initial and load your own monero private key and not a seed, it throws you a crazypass passphrase that it tells you to remember. I didn't write this down. Do I need this to restore my wallet? Or do i just remember my password?

Comment: imported my monerujo seed into the Monero-wallet-cli (monerujo not working anymore after the new release last week) but only the funds of the primary account are visible. As well when I enter "unspent_outputs" I see not more.
Basically I had two addresses on the monerujo, address A with 3 XMR and address B with 10 XMR. Only the 3 XMR were imported into the monero-wallet-cli.
My assumption was that address B is a subaddress and protected by the same seed. Is this wrong? And are you facing as well issues with monerujo since 7-10 days? It's loading but after about 20 seconds crashing. 100% repeat

Comment: @Schilling - Did you have multiple *accounts* in Monerujo or multiple subaddresses? Also, did you make sure to use a `Restore height` that was significantly in advance of the first transaction to your wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an encrypted partition on your device? Must be an iPhone, just copy your seed on a piece of paper, I printed out a crossword puzzle to fit all my seed words and found a crossword puzzle book with the same structure on one of the 400 pages of puzzles (;

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing Manerujo from your phone, first view and write down the mnemonic seed. When you reinstall the app, recover wallet from the seed.

https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md

You should be backing up your password and seed or keys anyway. Then just try with a test wallet to verify before using with your real wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your password, so it generates a new Crazypass which you will write down this time.
IIRC your password will not be enough to recover your wallet file.